# finding max(column) where column is varchar type using hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a column which is of type `varchar` like example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I wanted to get the max value so i tried the following query

```
select max(siAnswersId) from < table>
```

but this gives me wrong output so i tried using

`MAX(CAST(siAnswersId AS INTEGER))` and it works fine when I run in sql developer

but when I frame the query in hibernate as

```
select MAX(CAST(SI_ANSWERS_ID AS INTEGER)) from < table>
```

it gives me below error

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
<| \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX'<|    \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('<|
       +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'CAST' {originalText=CAST}<|
       \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'<|
          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'serviceins0_.SI_ANSWERS_ID'
{propertyName=siAnswersId,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=siAnswersId,path
{synthetic-alias}.siAnswersId,tableAlias=serviceins0_,
className=com.hp.api.management.nfv.questionnair.entities.ServiceInstanceAnswersEntity,
classAlias=s}<|
      |  +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}<|
      |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'siAnswersId' {originalText=siAnswersId}<|
      \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'INT' {originalText=INT}<|
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the "int" must be lowercase as

```
MAX(CAST(siAnswersId AS int))
```

It doesn't work is INT, integer, or Integer. The message actually says "no data type" as it doesn't recognize these as a valid data type.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX(CAST(siAnswersId AS INT))` should do. `INT` instead of `INTEGER`.